# Parallel Tasks Priority (JAVA)

Tags: java

Need help with parallel tasks. I need to make NO a priority in case one of the actors says no. Preventing the instance from getting stuck.

Make some changes to the process (BPMN) for consistent use of the parallel task.
I got some feedback from the workbench forum, giving me advice to use "send signal", but it still doesn't work and no working example.

Framework: **Cuba Platform**

Programming language: **Java**

Instance Stuck Sample:

[image: Instance stuck sample]

Process:

[image: Process]

Send Signal Idea:
[image: Send Signal Idea]

Been more specific need this idea to java.

```
import org.flowable.engine.ProcessEngines

def runtimeService = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine().getRuntimeService();

//Ermitteln der wartenden Execution des Auftragsprozesses
def executions = runtimeService.createExecutionQuery()
     .signalEventSubscriptionName('InputB-Signal')
     .processInstanceId('d87fe3bf-bc44-4061-48ca-56860e4b6d57')
     .list();
     
def variabeln = [
    'hallo' : 'Welt',
    'Java' : 'Duke'
]     

//Benachrichtigung an den Auftragprozess
executions.each { execution -> 
    log.debug("Execution ${execution.getId()}")
    runtimeService.signalEventReceived('InputB-Signal', execution.getId(), variabeln) 
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Omar, you are new here, so welcome.  Note,I will say, more code work is expected on this site.  Show us what you have attempted in Java.  Do check out the link from tgdavies...  and yes, the Business Process Model and Notation (BPMN) is pretty and all but does NOT help with the code issue you are having.  Note, no one here will write the code for you.  We'll help on a specific problem, not do your work for you from scratch.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I just made changes that I hope will try to solve my doubt. Since I have an example but not directly in java.